# How to use drawImage instead of scaled for performance

Tags: codenameone

I have a placeholder image that is scaled. I have seen in the blogs to use drawImage instead of scale for performance reasons.

```
placeholderForTable = (EncodedImage) theme.getImage("placeholderWithAnimate.png");
placeholderForTable = placeholderForTable.scaledEncoded(screenWidth, (screenWidth * 1 / 3));
```

1.Is the following better than the scaled above?

```
Image tmp = Image.createImage(screenWidth, screenWidth * 1 / 3, 0);
placeholderForTable = EncodedImage.createFromImage(tmp, false);
```

2. How can I use the drawImage to boost performance?

   placeholderForTable.getGraphics().drawImage(placeholderForTable, 0, 0, screenWidth, (screenWidth * 1 / 3));
      //It gives null pointer error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That advice is meant for `paint(Graphics)` code and not static code that scales once. In your case changing the usage of `scaled()` would probably not impact performance significantly since it would happen only once.

You need to inspect things that happen each frame e.g. the theme, hierarchy etc. and see if there are elements that would cost in terms of performance.